# firebase emails verified by link checker bots

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have implemented email verification in my app but i've noticed to email providers have bots that open the link before the user gets to see (thus verifying the email).

is there a way to prevent such behavior? or email verification by code or have action on the screen the user would need to click to verify?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than providing a direct link to Firebase (the default), you can [customize your email verification template](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7000714?authuser=0#actionlink) to direct the user to another location, such as your application, where they must press a button to complete the verification process. Then you can use the [`Auth.applyActionCode()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.Auth#applyactioncode) method with the `oobCode` that was supplied in the query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to process the verifications yourself if you wish to customize it. You can try it by generating email verification link using Admin SDK in a Cloud Function/Server

```
// Admin SDK API to generate the email verification link.
const useremail = 'user@example.com';
admin
  .auth()
  .generateEmailVerificationLink(useremail, actionCodeSettings)
  .then((link) => {
    // Construct email verification template, embed the link and send
    // using custom SMTP server.
    return sendCustomVerificationEmail(useremail, displayName, link);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Some error occurred.
  });
```

Now that you've sent the email, you'll have to self-host a page to that opens after opening that link.
You can find detailed explanation in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler)

That being said, you can implement reCaptcha or any verification service you want to use to make sure the user is not a bot and verify it in your custom handler.